# Change isRequired star position in Struts 1

Tags: struts

I am using Struts 1 on a form and need to mark some inputs as required. The thing is that the red star ('*') showing the required fields when marking them with `isRequired="true"` is by default shown right after the textbox:

[alt text http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/2345/input.png](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/2345/input.png)

Is there a way to change the star position to the left, right before "Input"?

If needed, the code of this is now:

```
<layout:text property="input" key="form.input" styleClass="FormInput" mode="E,E,I" isRequired="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to write your own custom tag that basically extends the layout:text tag but overrides the output (i.e. where the star is generated if the field has an error).

Start here: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html You could probably skip ahead to the "Examples" page, but the other stuff is good to know too

Comment: Would you be kind enough to tell me how to do this, or point me to the right tutorials/examples?